# Backbone.js Sign in to application using Twitter

Tags: backbone.js, twitter-oauth

I'm a complete newbie to Backbone.js and programming in general, I've searched high and low to find a tutorial on how to implement a "sign in with Twitter" functionality using Backbone.js JavaScript on the front-end and Java on the server-side, but to no avail.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thank you.

Comment: Just did something like this, but except on the server side using node.js. I actually thought it was easier than working with the API on the client side because there is a cool node plugin called passort.js. Do you want to Log in users via the backend?

Comment: People used to get on me about this, but do you mean "javascript" instead of "Java" they're different, really different! :)

Comment: at this point I doubt you're into node.js and such but I highly recommend it, if you are or do, check this out. http://scotch.io/tutorials/javascript/easy-node-authentication-setup-and-local great tutorial.

Comment: Thank you so much Michael, yes, I'm trying to learn Oracle Java as well on the server side and trying to learn Backbone.js on the client side.  I'm not oppose to doing it completely on the server-side, I just have to figure out how to allow for user's clicks and such, in order to get over to Twitter to sign in.

Comment: Interesting I'm so used to server side being ran on Apache or nginix, and now node/express with googles v8. I am taking some java classes for android. A lot of things are built on java...

Comment: Any chance you can show me what you did, minus all your super secret stuff?  I'd like give node.js a try.  Thanks.